# how to select SQL , age 20 first , and then all the rest from table PERSONS?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table contains 113 people.

48 of them are 20 years old. Now I am just selecting all people like

```
select * from persons
```

this will get me all persons, but 20 yr old are not the first 48 people.

I need the 20 yr old to be first 48 in 113 results.

something like

```
20 year ols ( 48 of them ), after that ..... all the rest in the table
```

How can I query this using PostgreSQL.

EDIT : there are age less than 20 too. after getting the first 48 , 20 yr olds, I dont care rest of the order I am getting the 48 to 113 people.

Comment: Please remove your mysql tag.

Comment: Please post a minimally reproduceable sample of data. There are too many unknowns about your data. Is 20 the youngest in the table? Is there a column that specifies age or just DOB?

Comment: `select x from y where age=20 union all select x from y where age<>20`

Comment: So, do you have a column that stores the date of birth?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hi , thank you for comment.We don't have no date of birth. Like mr VBoka said , I queried somethin like select * 
from persons
order by case when age in ('20') then age not in ('20') and isdeleted=1;
Currently I am trying to convert this to sequelize, any help ?

Comment: A column named "age" is a really bad idea. The value is essentially wrong already as it changes every day. You should store the date of birth and calculate the current age from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use order by :

```
select * 
from persons
order by age
```

You can use asc or desc but because default is asc you do not need to put it in your example.

```
select * 
from persons
order by age desc
```

After the comment from OP here is the new code(I do not know why but my firs assumption was that the value 20 is the lowest possible value... bad assumption):

```
select * 
from persons
order by case when age = 20 then 1 else 2 end
```

OR

```
select * 
from persons
order by (age = 20) desc
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e631a99aced0f82bbacc902aceec07d3)

Comment: there are age less than 20 too. but i need the first 48 to be 20 yr olds. after that i dont need any particular order. This query will get by ascending order , so i am getting 15 yr old first

Comment: Hi @thenoobdev133332323, I have added new code - the third example. I see that this is the same as the answer from lemon so... The 4th example is also added

Comment: Yes I will try Right Away

Comment: Hi @thenoobdev133332323 check the 4th example also.

Comment: ps: IAM STILL trying,... stackoverflow doest allow after 5 minute to edit. Currently I am trying to implement your above logic to " select * from emojams WHERE age in ('20')   or  
 age not IN ('20') and isdelted=1", Here I am selecting all the persons with owner age 20 , and users with age not 20 + isdeleted =1. In result I will get a mixed result. I will try to implement your logic such that, I will get the first 48 as age 20 person and only after that age not 20 plus isdeleted =1. ps: IAM STILL trying,... stackoverflow doest allow after 5 minute to edit

Answer (score 1):

If 20 is not your minimum age, you can use the `CASE` statement inside the `ORDER BY` clause, like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    persons
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN age = 20 THEN 0 
         ELSE 1 
    END ASC
```